# Simple sideways scrolling of images - UIScrollView or UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

I have a requirement to implement timed horizontal scrolling of several images which take up most of the screen (except for the top which will be occupied by a static navigation bar-like `UIView`).

It needs to be timed so the images can swap programmatically but also user-swipable so the user can flick between them if they choose to. There are no requirements for the user to be able to pinch, zoom, scroll within an individual image etc. as each image is exactly the size of the available remaining space on the screen.

Googling for how to do this turns up a plethora of possibilities, some say use an existing library, some say to use `UIScrollView`, others say to use a `UIPageViewControllers`.

Which of the possibilities is most suitable?

Its for iOS6 and iOS5.

Comment: You can consider using UICollectionView if you only wants to target iOS 6.0 + . PSTCollectionView which mimicks UICollectionView is also a good option.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention its for iOS 5 too.

Comment: Then you can consider using PSTCollectionView, with horizontal Scroll, you can make each collectionViewItem visible by incrementing the indexPath.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ATPagingView is a great library of code for exactly what you would need.  You will have to implement the timer yourself that switches the view, but it does have user enabled switching like you stated you need.

https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS